# AWS IAM ARN and wildcard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

From the AWS IAM ARN documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html, I can see wildcard use as shown below which is quite confusing.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ManageRichardAccessKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*AccessKey*",
                "iam:GetUser"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/Richard"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListForConsole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:ListUsers",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the first statement `"Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/Richard"`, why are we not specifying the account number and just substituting with wildcard "*" - I understand that in the context of S3  this is left blank, but over here it is wildcard - what does the wild card here really mean? The wildcard appears to give it a meaning like "any account" but isnt this incorrect?

Also, for the second statement `"Resource": "*"`, does this mean ListUsers for any resource? which does not make any sense - should this not be something like `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:` indicating list users for this AWS account (123456789012)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the queries actually work (I didn't test them):

- Yes, leaving out the **account number** is a 'little' dangerous because it would also be permitting the user that has this policy to manage access keys for a same-named user in a different account, but the receiving account would not honor the request so it is safe.
- The `ListUsers` command does not actually take many parameters (just a prefix), so it's really an **"all or nothing" API call**. Please note that it only applies to requesting a list of users, nothing else. (That is, there is no concept of calling "ListUsers for a resource".)

See: [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Identity And Access Management - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_identityandaccessmanagement.html)

Comment: "permitting the user that has this policy to manage access keys for a same-named user in a different account.. but only if that other account also allows it"-Could you explain this a bit more John.Lets say there is a user Richard with the policy attached and the AWS account is 12345678901.There is another AWS account 98765432109 with the same user Richard. Even if account 98765432109 allows Richard in account 12345678901 cross account access, it would only be through roles and the policy in question would have no effect-isnt it? In what way could the account 98765432109 allow dangerous access?

Comment: I guess my use-case mostly applies to S3, which has its own policies via Bucket Policies. Account-A could grant User-A access to Bucket-B in Account-B, but it would only work if the Bucket Policy on Bucket-B also permitted it. In contrast, if User-A had zero S3 permissions, then the Bucket Policy on Bucket-B alone would not be sufficient to grant access, since User-A can't make any S3 calls. But, thinknig about it in the context of this question, it doesn't apply to IAM since there is no equivalent to a Bucket Policy, so the scenario in the question would be quite safe. Answer updated.